# How to write an if condition for return key or enter ket

Tags: java

I am writing a program in java in which I want that if the user presses the "return" key then the next statement should be executed. But, I can't understand how to write an if condition for "return key" or enter key in the code. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you show us what you already have tried?

Comment: This question has many conflicting interpretations, each with different answer.  It is "too broad".  You need to be more specific.  Describe in detail that *kind* of program you are writing, and what you are trying to detect.  Alternatively, show us the relevant part your code ...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something you could check for `nextLine()` with a `Scanner`.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Press enter to continue");
s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Thank you");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it as a result of hitting return in a text field or text area, you can add a key pressed action listener, then have an if condition to check if the enter key was pressed?

Such as,

```
if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
   //do some code
}
```

Alternatively you could look into key bindings.

Comment: It is probably better to compare with `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` instead of the fix literal.